# Visual Studio 2017 dosen't copy assembly of project indirect referenced into compile folder

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

I have a big solution of Visual Studio 2017 with 97 projects all with .Net Framework 4.7.2. I noticed that one of the final projects doesn't works property. Simplifying, this final project A (windows application type) depends on project B and project C (classes library type), and projects B and C depends on D (classes library type too). This is:

```
A < B < D
A < C < D
```

The projects D, C and B compile properly.
The projects C and B contains in output folder the D assembly.

The project A compile properly, but in output folder appears the assemblies A, B and C but doesn't appears D assembly.

My Visual Studio Version is the last one: 15.9.1. In previously versions I had the same problem with another projects (easily I could discover in a Click Once project), but after I updated the Visual Studio to 15.8.7 dissapeared. Now I tried to update to last versión, but I continues happening.

Any idea?

Comment: Check that you are using project references for everything, and not referencing the dlls directly.

Comment: a: what kind of project is this (sdk-style/.net-core-style? or the more traditional style?); b: what kind of references are they - are they package references? project references? dll references? being pragmatic: what happens if you simply make A additionally reference D?